# Add files to core or to local? (Not override)

Tags: module, magento-1, overrides, core, 3rd-party-library

I am installing the RedSys module http://www.redsys.es following their guide.
At some point of their guide they say the following:

> 4.Se deben colocar los ficheros de la carpeta “Source”, incluido en el
>   módulo de pago de REDSYS, en el siguiente directorio del módulo de
>   Magento: (TRANSLATION: The Source folder's files must be included in the following Magento's module directory:)

```
your_domain/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source
```

The thing is that they are writing new files in the core, so I wonder whether or not it would be the same if I write these files in local in the folder:

```
your_domain/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source
```

I ask this because I want to avoid problems in future Magento upgrades and I think that if they work the same way then the second approach would be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the first rule in Magento development : **never touch the core**

You can either:

- create your own module in `app/code/local` and add the library in the module folder if that library is already Magento code
- or if it's pure PHP and not Magento code still create your own module in `app/code/local` and add the library under the `lib` folder

In both case you will have to use `include` / `require` statements to be able to use your library or customize the autoloader of Magento so you can use those classes directly.

Also as a gift here is a Ben Marks meme to remember :

[image]